# automated copy of all pages with relative paths using php / mysql

Tags: php, mysql, download, relative-path

I have access to a website that I pay to use that has a really lame user lookup query. The information I need pertaining to users requires me to click each individual name and a modal window pops up with the info in it. I don't manage or own this site so I have no intentions of trying to access their DB directly - I just want to access the info using the (legal) means they allow.

This wouldn't be an issue if I only needed like 10 but I have to do 3200!!!!

I want to download all the info on each user page into a hosted MySQL DB. The website accesses the user pages with a javascript function and the URL looks like this ...

xxxxxxx.com/ModalReport?sharedID=0000&modalType=user

by changing the sharedID and directly using the URL in my browser, I can access each user's page (yay no modal!!!) - HOWEVER it must be running sessions because if I'm not logged in to begin with, I cannot access the page

Is there code or even an app that will access each page using the URL, copy to a db and then increment he shareID + 1 and start over and then stop when it runs out of pages?

thanks!!

Comment: just use for loop then file_get_contents, then get your values, insert to db. the loop should do the increment

Comment: forgot to mention the site requires a login and apparently is running sessions - if I try to access the page without being logged in first, I get the login screen.

Comment: then you need to use curl instead of file_get_contents, of course you need to use your credentials on the post values